# Azure IoT Hub endpoint to ADLS Gen2 with custom file name format

Tags: azure-iot-hub

When creating a custom endpoint in IoT Hub which sends data to a ADLS Gen2 storage account is it possible to use values from the incoming message, message body, or twin data when building out the file name format?

The default is “{iothub}/{partition}/{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}/{HH}/{mm}“ and I would like to include other properties in the path like {deviceId} or {$twin.propery.foo}. I want to be able to organize the files using custom fields right from an IoT hub route to ADLS.

I know I can accomplish this with an EventHub Function trigger but I am hoping there is a way to do this just with the file name format.

[image: endpoint creation for reference]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, custom file name format is not available while routing messages.
Please see the Uservoice created for this feature here: [extend the route to blob file name format with dynamic parameters such as deviceId or messageType](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot-hub-dps-sdks/suggestions/35911816-extend-the-route-to-blob-file-name-format-with-dyn)

Please provide your feedback and upvote for this feature.

Comment: AS of 18 September 2023, the above link is not valid  new link is https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/4b8f152d-c809-ed11-a81b-6045bd8606d4   Please upvote it.